# Shut down computer every night, and wake it up every morning

Tags: shutdown, cron, rtc

I have seen other topics about this, and have attempted it many times, but it fails for me.

I have a desktop that I want to schedule to shut down at midnight, every night, and wake up at 6 am.

I ran sudo crontab -e and added `@daily poweroff`.

I also edited /etc/crontab and added `00  0   * * *    root   poweroff`
.
Above that, I added `00  0   * * *    root   rtcwake -m no -l -t $(date +%s -d "tomorrow 6:00")`

The idea is that cron would get the message to wake up the next morning, and then get the poweroff message. This doesn't work, though. I'm not sure if the rtcwake part is doing anything, because the computer never shuts down in the first place.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: if you shutdown your computer then Operating System (Ubuntu in this case) can't do anything. it may depends on BIOS I think

Answer (score 0):

1. your poweroff option in the crontab is okay. Test it.
2. The wake up needs to be set up in Bios, so remove the rtc-wake line from crontab and reboot, go to Bios and set up wake up there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go old skool you set your BIOS to boot when AC power is applied, then plug your PC into an outlet timer that turns on at your desired boot time.  Set your daily poweroff as above and have the timer go off after that.